# Unable to use CSS modules in CRA 2.0

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

React now supports CSS modules in CRA without ejecting. But I am still unable to use them.

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1"
  },
```

My react-scripts version is also > 2.0

```
import React from "react";

import classes from "./Layout.module.css";

const Layout = props => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>Toolbar, SideDrawer, Backdrop</div>
      <main className={classes.Content}>{props.children}</main>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

Layout.css

```
.Content {
  margin: 10rem;
}
```

I am using them as mentioned here

https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet.

This is the error I am getting:

```
./src/components/Layout/Layout.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './Layout.module.css' in '/home/tft/Desktop/My_Workspace/Reactjs-Projects/Personal Projects/burger-king/src/components/Layout'
```

Comment: Can you add your `Layout.module.css` and an example of the folder structure.

Comment: added in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question you state that the css file is named `Layout.css`, but I think it should be `Layout.module.css` to work. Or you just forgot to name it properly in here?